# The four requisites for trade

Tags: terminology, lay-buddhism

In the [Vanijja Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.079.than.html) Buddha talks about the four requisites for trade. I couldn't find the four anywhere, does anybody know what he refers to?

Comment: Strange sutta to me, also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requisites for trade are not requirements for trading, they are four objects which are traded.

They are [four items](http://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/the-bhikkhus-rules/d/doc1739.html) which are required for monastic living, namely clothing, food, medicine and shelter.